# location property is not allowed for a deployment at resource group scope

Tags: azure, arm, azure-sql-database, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I created linked ARM template and trying to deploy but I am getting below error.

I am deploying Sql Server and Server Database using linked templates.  Individual ARM (Sql Server and sql database is working fine).

**Error: InvalidDeployment;
Message=The 'location' property is not allowed for a deployment at resource
group scope. Please see https://aka.ms/deploy-to-subscription for usage
details.**

If I remove location and trying to deploy I am getting below error.

**The location property is  required for this definition**

Is my mistake is in Schema version or api version or something?

```
New-AzResourceGroupDeployment -Name "ARMLinkedDeployment" -ResourceGroupName "Test-POC-RG" -TemplateFile ".......\MainTemplates\SqlApp\azuredeploy.json" -TemplateParameterFile ".....\MainTemplates\SqlApp\parameters.json"
```

**parameters.json**

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "sqlserver_linkedTemplatepath": {
        "value": "https://stvirtuosotest.blob.core.windows.net/armlinkedtemplates/azuredeploysql.json"
    },
    "sqldb_linkedTemplatepath": {
        "value": "https://stvirtuosotest.blob.core.windows.net/armlinkedtemplates/azuredeploysqldb.json"
    },
    "sqlserver_parameters_linkedTemplatepath": {
        "value": "https://stvirtuosotest.blob.core.windows.net/armlinkedtemplates/azuredeploy.sqlparameters.json"
    },
    "sqldb_parameters_linkedTemplatepath": {
        "value": "https://stvirtuosotest.blob.core.windows.net/armlinkedtemplates/azuredeploy.sqldbparameters.json"
    }
}
}
```

**azuredeploy.json file**

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "sqlserver_linkedTemplatepath": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The sql server arm template json file path from storage account.."
        }
    },
    "sqldb_linkedTemplatepath": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The sql database deploy arm template json file path from storage account."
        }
    },
    "sqldb_parameters_linkedTemplatepath": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The sql database arm parameters file json file path from storage account."
        }
    },
    "sqlserver_parameters_linkedTemplatepath": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "The sql server arm parameters json file path from storage account."
        }
    }
},

"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
        "name": "sqlDbDeployment",
        "resourceGroup": "[resourceGroup().name]",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "[parameters('sqldb_linkedTemplatepath')]",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            },
            "parametersLink": {
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "uri": "[parameters('sqldb_parameters_linkedTemplatepath')]"
            }
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "sqlServerDeployment"
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
        "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
        "name": "sqlServerDeployment",
        "resourceGroup": "[resourceGroup().name]",
        "properties": {
            "mode": "Incremental",
            "templateLink": {
                "uri": "[parameters('sqlserver_linkedTemplatepath')]",
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
            },
            "parametersLink": {
                "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
                "uri": "[parameters('sqlserver_parameters_linkedTemplatepath')]"
            }
        }
    }

],
"outputs": {
    "sqldbresourceid": {
        "type": "object",
        "value": "[reference('sqlDbDeployment').outputs.resourceGroup.resourceId]"
    },
    "sqlserverresourceid": {
        "type": "object",
        "value": "[reference('sqlServerDeployment').outputs.resourceGroup.resourceId]"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: @RoadRunner updated details as its missed last time

Comment: @RoadRunner After adding that , I am getting "The 'location' property is not allowed for a deployment at resource group scope"

Comment: @RoadRunner getting The location property is required for this definition error.

Comment: Could you please tell me where you define location?

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS Firstly, You might want to secure your parameters file

Looks like you have already addressed the issue with Location parameter. Final teething issue is in the individual templates, if you can change the output types from `Object` to `string` and in the Main ARM template if you change it to `.outputs.sqldatabaseresourceId.value` you should get it to work

Comment: Yes Thanks @HariSubramaniam.
the problem is inn main ARM template .outputs.sqldatabaseresourceId.value Thanks. this makes my ARM working success

Comment: @PavanKumarGVVS Glad to know you have it working now. Please post what worked for you as an answer below so it helps others in the community as well.

Comment: @BhargaviAnnadevara answer is same as the template code i shared in my question except output i changed and make sure you don't add location parameter in master template. if you want you can exclude output parameters in master template and use output parameter in linked template. Thats best option

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I fixed the same issue.

parameters.json file

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "value": "eastus2"
        }
    }
}
```

azuredeploy.json file

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
            "name": "deployment1",
            "resourceGroup": "[resourceGroup().name]",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "Incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                    "relativePath": "templates/template.json"
                },
                "parameters": {
                    "location": {
                        "value" : "[parameters('location')]"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So the location can be used from the template.json as required.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-test-cases#location-uses-parameter